# Ask for Password whenever you click on the app (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using objective c with xib (rather than storyboard).

I'm really bummed out. I'm making a chat app and need the app to ask for the passcode whenever the user clicks it.

I really don't know what to write inside the applicationDidBecomeActive method. Please help.

(FYI my root view is a tab bar application and it has many sub views so whenever my user clicks on the app, after he types his password, the password should go away and he should return to wherever he was)

Thank You All for Your Help :)

Comment: Can you share some code to show what you have tried? Or what application tutorial you may be following if you are following one?

Comment: handle root view by authentication

Comment: Make an `UIVIew` on top of your `tabBar` or `modalViewController`
and ask for password in it. if password correct then hide the view/dissmiss controller

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is :
Make an `UIVIew` on top of your `tabBar` or `modalViewController` and ask for password in it. if password correct then `hide` the `view`/`dissmiss controller`.
This is not the best solution.

More proper solution is:

Make you root view a password `viewConntroller` put all the logic there, and if the password is correct call you `tabbar`.

You can do it in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` 
put your `passWordViewController`... On correct password delegate to `appDelegate` and dismiss your `passWordViewController` and show the `tabBar`.